# Extracting comment url from wordpress function

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing some ajax script and using wordpress and my question is: is there a way to extract a comment url from a wordpress function somehow? The function I'm using in the loop looks like that:

```
<?php comments_popup_link('Discuss &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '| ', ''); ?>
```

And the HTML output of that looks like this:

```
<a href="http://www.somepage.com/staging/2010/06/15/sadfasfregw/#respond" title="Comment on sadfasfregw"><span class="dsq-postid-17546">View Comments</span></a>| 
<a class="post-edit-link" href="http://www.somepage.com/staging/wp-admin/post.php?action=edit&post=17546" title="Edit post">Edit</a>
```

However, I'm only interested in src (http://www.somepage.com/staging/2010/06/15/sadfasfregw/#respond). Is there a way to get it from there and then use it in later reference? Does some kind of function or anything like that exists in wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $comments_url = get_permalink() . '#respond'; ?>
```